# Show message as a table in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am new in programing and I have to design a project as a part of my Uni project ... I have almost completed 70% of design but would like to show a massage as table.

Should I have database ??? ... How can I link it to message ??

My code is

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Then MessageBox.Show("Please, Find Your Calories First")
        If TextBox1.Text > "2400" Or TextBox1.Text > "2300" Then MessageBox.Show("What should I write here????")
```

should I have database ???

Comment: what do you mean by show message as table?

Comment: Warning "999" > "2400" = True.......

Comment: also TextBox1.Text = Nothing (is always False)

Comment: `TextBox1.Text = Nothing` and `TextBox1.Text > "2400"` scares me. You should pick a book on VB.NET first.

Comment: Instead of having it Textbox1.Text = Nothing. Havit Textbox1.Text = ""

Comment: Thanx Steve and Neolisk for ur feedback and ur advice as well .. I think I didn't give u enough information about my program .. The idea of my program is to calculate the calories that u need and then it will show u the appropriate meals for this calories .. There are two Buttons and one textbox .. I used the first button to calculate the calories (the calories will be calculated if the user input all program requirements such as weight, height, age ...) the calories (calculation result) will be shown in the textbox .. and I used the second button to show the appropriate meals for this result

Comment: I have written TextBox1.Text = Nothing because if u do not calculate ur calories using the first button u will get message asking to calculate it first .. and I have written TextBox1.Text > "2400" (this is as an example) because if ur calories become somewhere between 2300 and 2400 calories .. this button will show u the appropriate meals for u .. Because there are many information in each meal, I would like to present it is schedule .. So, it become easier for user to read and understanding the meals ..My question is .. How can I do that? ..Should I build database ? and how can I connect it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by table.... but a couple of points any way...

You should abstract the code from the button click, that way you can re-use it on another event. you just create a new sub and call it from the button click like this

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    CaloriesChecker()

End Sub
```

This is your method re-written as a case statement, an integer variable "calories" has been assigned to your text box, that will ensure that you can evaluate the number.

Using the case statement you can set your boundaries for Calorie.... Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by table.

```
Private Sub CaloriesChecker()

    Dim calories As Integer = TextBox1.Text
    Dim message As String

    Select Case calories
        Case ""
            message = "Please, Find Your Calories First"
        Case Is > 2300
            message = "whatever you want to say"
    End Select

    messagebox.show(message)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanx guyh92 for ur answer .. I'm sorry .. I didn't mention many information about my program in the question .. I have just written program details in my last comments .. Actually,  I need my massage present in table to be easy for user to read and understand .. For example Case Is > 2300
            message = "I would this to be a table"

Answer (score 0):

The best of beside that showing message, you still need a database to fill in the meal lik

```
+-----------+-------------------+
| Meal Type |    Calories       |
+-----------+-------------------+
| Bread     |     XXXXXX        |
|  ......   |     ..........    |
+-----------+-------------------+
```

Some thing like this, cause it will made user easy to input or even don't need them to input their calories. Every time they pick the meal, then a textbox will auto get the value(calories) from what the user pick..

Why i suggest like that? Cause not every user of your program know the exact calories. So the best is create a database to contain that.

Q : How about if their meal not contain at database?
A : Then you should made a button to called new form to add new meal and calories by the user

Isn't that you want?
Also about your code

```
If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Then MessageBox.Show("Please, Find Your Calories First")
        If TextBox1.Text > "2400" Or TextBox1.Text > "2300" Then MessageBox.Show("What should I write here????")
```

i dont think it would best strategy for PROGRAMMER who would like his/her program to be favorite by other. Cause if they hard to find it, they will feel this program hard to use then bored, then delete. Isn't it?

So, the best if made new database. About calculate, you can made the button to calculate it to be true calories to be consumer for ages or weight or etc for what you want to be best

Comment: Actually, my program is calculating calories ... and it will show the appropriate meal for this amount of calories.. the program will see in which range ur calories is located and then it will display the meals to u